# Calling parent's initializer based on decisions in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I have this code for calling parent initializer in C++.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(const string& a) {}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(const string& b) : A(b) {}
};
```

I guess I can decorate a little bit with parent initializer like this.

```
B(const string& b) : A(b + "!!") {}
```

Then, what about when I need some decision logic for setting up the parent initializer?
I tried this but I got error message.

```
B(const string& b) {
    if (...) {
        A(b + "x");
    } else {
        A(b + "y");
    }
}

>> ERROR 

hier.cpp: In constructor 'B::B(const string&)':
hier.cpp:16:2: error: no matching function for call to 'A::A()'
```

Comment: you can not call the constructor of A like a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have complicated logic you want to execute it is best to put it in a separate function:

```
std::string modify(const std::string &b) {
    if (...) {
        return b + "x";
    } else {
        return b + "y";
    }
}
```

Then you can use that function in your initializer list:

```
B(const string& b) : A(modify(b)) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

You encode it in the initializer list:

```
B(const string& b) : A(b + ((...) ? "x" : "y")) {}
```

If "decision logic" gets more complicated, you factor it out into a separate function (often a private static member).

Answer (score 1):

You can put a static private method in the constructor of the base class, like this:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    B(const string& b) : A(initval(b)){}
private:
    static string initval(const string& b) {
        if (...)
            return b + "x";
        else
            return b + "y";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by sth, I would also make the modify function a static method of B.

```
std::string B::modify(const std::string &b) {
    if (...) {
        return b + "x";
    } else {
        return b + "y";
    }
}
```

In the class definition:

```
static std::string B::modify(const std::string &b)
```

Then, use it:

```
B(const string& b) : A(B::modify(b)) {}
```

The reason for this is that it will be fully encapsulated within B, rather than as a separate function outside. It would be more object oriented.

Answer (score 0):

As long, as you are calling the same constructor (use the same signature for you initializer), you can go with Casey's answer. However, if you want to do something like this:

```
B(const string& b) {
    if (...) {
        A(b + "x");
    } else {
        A(foo, bar);
    }
}
```

then you are doomed. There is no such thing in C++. The only way around it is to call a default constructor and then do the initialization using a specialized member function (usually called init() or something like it). It is the same technique you need when you have a bunch of different constructors that should be implemented by calling each other, which sadly is forbidden in C++. Both issues are not present in such beautiful languages as Objective-C.